# No such file or directory java while executing script

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have to install a program. When I run this command:

```
sudo ./Vivado-Hardware-Server/xsetup
```

I get the following error:

```
./Xilinx_HW_Server_Lin_2015.2_0626_1/xsetup: line 67: 
/home/user/Xilinx_HW_Server_Lin_2015.2_0626_1/tps/lnx32/jre/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

`/home/user/Xilinx_HW_Server_Lin_2015.2_0626_1/tps/lnx32/jre/bin/java` exists and its permissions are: `-rwxr-xr-x`

The OS is Ubuntu 64 bit and the Java version is:

java version "1.7.0_79"

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.6) (7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.15.04.1)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

[This](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Installation-and-Licensing/installing-on-ubuntu/td-p/587343) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454946/error-executing-xilinx-ise-design-suite-bin-filejava-xsetup) did not help me. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

This error is most-probably caused by a missing shared-object (dynamic library).  Try running `ldd` on the binary the `xsetup` script tries to execute (`…/jre/bin/java`), this will list the libraries it needs to execute and tell if it found them.  `lnx32` in the path of the complaining program is suggesting that it is a 32bit executable.  Since you are on a 64bit host, you will most-probably need to install some 32bit libraries currently not present on your system.

Comment: If I run  `ldd ./xsetup` I get _not a dynamic executable_. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote this ambiguous.  See edit.